# Why display:none does not hide Struts 2 tag like <s:textfield>

Tags: jquery, css, jsp, struts2, struts-tags

I wonder why the `div` tag is not able to hide the Struts2 tags, I am using a `div` which should hide on load, and `onChange` I am calling jQuery which toggles the `div` tag...

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#t").click(function(){
        alert("I Know Its Not Working");
        $('#tt').toggle();
    });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<s:form >
<div style="display: none;" id="tt">
<s:textfield></s:textfield>
</div>
</s:form>
<input type="button" id="t">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You div is starting hidden, so you can't see your <p>, but you see the <input type="text"/> on load ? IS this the problem ?

Comment: No Andrea,i am able to hide Html tags...even I am able display Html Tags(OnToggle) inside div....the problem  with struts2 tags..:( You can try putting s:textfiled in div and toggle it...:) :)

Comment: Yes but once the JSP is rendered, your <s:textfield/> will be translated to <input type="text"/>. So I'm still not getting what your problem is :|

Comment: @AndreaLigios can u do something like this....create a struts2 Form....<s:form><div id="hide" style="display: none;"><s:textfield value="kk"></s:textfield></div><s:form>  Then toggle the div using jquery....plz just try doing this...

Comment: @AndreaLigios main thing is it should be inside s:form(div tag)

Comment: @AndreaLigios u can see my Code...

Comment: 1) Why 4.01 ? Can't you use HTML5 Doctype def ? 2) Why jQuery 1.3.2 that is jurassik ? Any chance of migrating to a newer version ? 3) Please post the GENERATED html, from View Source, so we can understand what is exactly happening in your html. Since javascript runs client side, and s:form translation before (server side), it can't be the culprit

Comment: @goodyzain Why did you try to hide some content from the open eye, do you think that the size of the document is optimized to open it in the browser? Also like any other program that is using a dead code is discouraged.

Comment: @RomanC No i dont want to  hide some content from the open eye,Or something...in my scenario Based on User Input i need to hide and show <s:textfield> Like...Do You Have Coupon Code:Yes/No  On Yes i need to display <s:textfield> for Coupon Code..:(

Answer (score 1):

By default Struts2 uses `xhtml` theme for generating html content of form fields like `textfield` tag. This theme is using a `<table>` layout with `<tr><td>` for input elements. This breaks your design because these elements is placed outside `<div>` tag. If you want to use `<div>` instead of `<tr><td>` for your input fields then you can choose `css_xhtml` theme. If you want to omit to generate `<tr><td>` or `<div>` then you can use `simple` theme. For example

```jsp
<s:form theme="simple">
 <div style="display: none;" id="tt">
   <s:textfield name="myfield" />
 </div>
</s:form>
```

**References:**

- [Themes and templates](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/themes-and-templates)

Answer (score 0):

i tested . working 100% for me :)

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //jquery methods go here...


  $("#btnhidediv").change(function(){

        $("#togglediv").toggle();

    });



});
</script>



</head>
<body>
<form>
<div  id="togglediv" style="display: none;">
<s:textfield  type="text" name="xyz" key="xyz" size="11" label="xyz"></s:textfield><br />

<p>Hieeeeeeeeeee</p>

</div>
<input type="text" id="btnhidediv">
</form>
<body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ha ha Sorry to tell this...can u put that div inside a s:form and run...???actually i forgot to put form...looks like the problem Arieses with s:form

Comment: @MSR You are doing something different by not using the `<s:form>` tag, which renders a table.

Comment: @goodyzain Please use only single punctuation marks except in rare circumstances where they're actually important. Here they're just noise.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yea Sure...:)