# Hiding both textfield and label in Struts2

Tags: html, jsp, struts2, themes, struts-tags

I have tried to hide both label and field in Struts 2 by using below approaches

#### Approach #1

```
<s:textfield style="display:none;" label="test">
```

It hides only textbox not the label.

#### Approach #2

```
<s:form theme="simple">
    <div style="display:none;" id="test">
        <s:label>test</s:label>
        <s:textfield>
    </div>
```

It hides both label and field.

Is there anyway to hide both label and textfield without using `theme` in Struts2 ?

I am looking for this because I am trying to add a new field to an already existing form. If I use `theme` then all my existing styling is disturbed.

Comment: Why do you hide fields? You can use `theme` attribute in other tags also.

Comment: I should display fields based on drop down value. As of now they are using xhtml as theme for existing form. I tried to change it but all the styling is getting disturbed.

Comment: So there is some js involved. You can use js to hide fields also. Look at the generated source to find out what to hide.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24382127/573032

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a hidden field and assign some text value to it. i.e, a hidden text field.
Instead of that you can directly, create a hidden field in Struts2 using the below tag:

```
<s:hidden name="url" label="" value="http://google.co.in/" />
```

`<s:hidden>` renders an HTML input element of type hidden, populated by the specified property from the ValueStack.
The [Hidden field Documentation](https://struts.apache.org/docs/hidden.html) contains the list of all parameters that `<s:hidden>` supports. You can also find `label` as attribute in it.

The other way is you can **change/toggle** the visibility property of the **text-Field/label** based on the value of drop down box for your query in comment using javascript/jquery. By-default visibilty value is `visible`, so no need to add default value.

```
<s:textfield name="id" label="Product Id" cssStyle="visibility:hidden" />
```

To hide the `<s:label>`  use the below code:

```
<s:label cssStyle="visibility:visible" id="productLabel"/> 
<!--use the below Javascript code in your toggling logic-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("productLabel").style.visibility ="hidden";
</script>
```

This code will be resulted into below in HTML, you can use the same logic as used with text-field to hide this label:

```
<label style="visibility:hidden" id="productLabel"/>
```

**For your question to hide both field and label in** `<s:textfield label="destinationterminal">` i.e,

```
<s:form>
 <div style="display: none;" id="test1">
    <s:textfield id="destinationTerminal1" label="DESTINATION TERMINAL"/>
  </div>
</s:form>
```

Use the below JQuery code:

```
$('label[for=destinationTerminal1], input#destinationTerminal1').hide();
```

Comment: I should hide the textfields on page load .  Based on drop down value I should display them for input from users

Comment: For this you have to use javascript/jquery to change the property of your textfields based on drop down value.

Comment: How the `visibility` is different from `display` in this context?

Comment: Rohit it is helpful. I am able to hide them with visibility:hidden property. But when try to change the property in Javascript it is making visible only the textbox not the label.

Comment: If we are using two different tags for label and textbox, then for aligning them in single line we should use theme="simple" again for tags.

Comment: First thing is there is no relation in hiding an element with theme in struts 2. please provide the code used to add the new field to already existing form. Instead of <s:label> you can use label attribute of text-field so that there will be no alignment issue.

Comment: @RohitGaikwad The whole question is about how to do it with *label attribute of text-field*. And you still haven't answered my question about differences.

Comment: This is the code I have used by creating new form <s:form theme="simple"><div style="display: none;" id="test1">
 <s:label value="DESTINATION TERMINAL"></s:label><s:textfield id="destinationTerminal1"  /></div>. In already existing form they are creating 
<s:textfield  label="destinationterminal" id="simplRoute_destination1" key="destination" />

Comment: @Aleksandr , It's not label attribute check the code provided it's <s:label>

Comment: @AleksandrM you are correct. I am trying to find solution to do with single tag and not using any struts theme

Comment: @RohitGaikwad Was referring to your last comment about using label attribute instead of `<s:label>`.

Comment: <s:label> is used in new form. I did it for alternative solution and show all the hidden fields at the bottom of already existing form. I used theme="simple" for new form.My question was how to hide both field and label in <s:textfield label="destinationterminal">

Comment: Whats the issue using this code? <s:form>
 <div style="display: none;" id="test1">
  <s:textfield id="destinationTerminal1" label="DESTINATION TERMINAL"/>
 </div>
</s:form> I guess hiding text-field would also hide the label.

Comment: If I use new form, I need to add all the fields at the end of existing form. My requirement was to add fields in the middle of  existing form.

Answer (score 1):

The *Columbus' Egg* is: use `theme` only on the tag, not on the whole form:

```xhml
<s:form>
    <div style="display:none;" id="test">
        <s:label>test</s:label>
        <s:textfield theme="simple">
    </div>
```

This won't affect anything else.

Comment: Is there a way to hide both label and textfield without using theme?

Comment: Struts2 uses themes to generate code. A different theme, a different code generated from each tag. The default one is the XHTML theme, that generates a <tr><td> for each tag. If you use it, you will have a <tr><td> surrounding your tags without being able to give them an id, for example, to hide them later. Then use simple theme everywhere, or use simple theme only on your tags, or use simple HTML instead of Struts tags. Is it clear enough ?

Comment: Then please remember to accept it when you've finished your tests

Answer (score 0):

I ran a demo with fake data on a Struts2 testing application I have using:

Struts JSP:

```
<s:form>
<s:select label="Reason"
    headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select a Reason"
    list="#{'1':'Site Bug', '2':'Other'}"
    name="reason"
    value="0" />
<s:textfield name="textField" label="Other"></s:textfield>
</s:form>
```

JavaScript Demo:

```js
$('select[id=_reason]').change(function() {
  var value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
  $('label[for=_textField]').hide();
  $('input[id=_textField]').hide();
  if (value && $.trim(value) === '2') {
    $('label[for=_textField]').show();
    $('input[id=_textField]').show();
  }
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="" action="" method="post">

  <label for="_reason">Reason</label>
  <select name="reason" id="_reason">
    <option value="-1">Select a Reason</option>
    <option value="1">Site Bug</option>
    <option value="2">Other</option>
  </select>

  <br>
  <br>
  <label for="_textField">Other</label>
  <input type="text" name="textField" value="" id="_textField">
</form>
```

You have to adjust the `id` values according to your form and `(value && $.trim(value) === '2')` that line according to your select option values.