# UI is not loading properly (Struts 1 to Struts 2)

Tags: jsp, templates, struts2, themes, struts-1

I'm migrating an application from Struts 1 to Struts 2, when I changed the `form` tag to `s:form` in the JSP file, the style and alignment loaded wrong, but when I leave the `form` tag, the page loaded properly.

I added the `taglib` and `!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC`

Do you have an idea why happens this?

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. There's no information here that can be used to help. It *sounds* like you're unaware of S2 themes. You cannot do a direct translation of JSP pages from S1 to S2 without understand what S2 does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Struts2 uses [themes and templates](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/themes-and-templates) for their tags.

You can learn [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24382127/573032) to get know which HTML content is generated when using Struts UI tags.

> By default Struts2 uses xhtml theme for generating html content of form fields like textfield tag. This theme is using a  layout with  for input elements. This breaks your design because these elements is placed outside  tag. If you want to use  instead of  for your input fields then you can choose `css_xhtml theme`. If you want to omit to generate  or  then you can use simple theme. For example

```
<s:form theme="simple">
 <div>
   <s:textfield name="myfield" />
 </div>
</s:form>
```